# Export choices from a Sharepoint list choice field to csv

Tags: csv, powershell, sharepoint, export

I'm new to SharePoint, but I'm looking to export all choices in a Choice field in a SharePoint list to a .csv file, using powershell.

Hopefully the file will look like:

```
"Choices"
"Choice1"
"Choice2"
"Choice3"
```

and so on. I need the choices in a .csv file, that I use for inputs in another powershell script.

I have tried googling, but every result seems to be on how to export the result for a specific choice, like the example below:
http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2015/06/05/using-powershell-and-the-sharepoint-2013-csom-to-export-list-data/

Context:
We maintain a list of IPs (and relevant information) that has access to our test websites. We maintain the list and then manually white-list the IPs on the websites. Since we have 20 websites at the moment and the number is increasing, we want to automate it, so we only have to maintain the SharePoint list and "magic" white-lists the IPs on the websites. The choice field mentioned is the websites, hence when we add new websites, I don't want to update a .txt or csv file manually, I just want it to be created based on the choices available in the SharePoint list.

Comment: I can see it's called choice field values. There seems to be help to find here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx#Set_and_Get_a_Multi-Choice_Field
I'll look at it.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're running script on a SharePoint web front end server, use the server object model**

If you're not running this from the SharePoint management shell, you'll want to start by adding the SharePoint snapin

```
add-pssnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Now that you have access to the SharePoint object model, you can get the list...

```
$web = get-spweb http://your.web.url
$list = $web.lists["List Title"]
```

Then get the field...

```
$field = $list.Fields | where-object {$_.title -eq "Field Title"}
# you can also get the field by its internal name like so:
# $field = $list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("FieldInternalName")
```

Then export the field choices to a CSV and dispose of the SPWeb object.

```
$field.choices | Export-Csv -path "\WhereverYouWant\YourFile.csv" -notype
$web.dispose()
```

**If you're running the script from outside the SharePoint environment, use the client object model**

These approach requires a bit of C# code due to Powershell not playing so nice with .NET methods that expect generic types.

The gist of it is that you'll write a static C# method that you can invoke from Powershell to get the data you want. In this case, getting the field schema as XML is a great way to get at the available field choices.

```
# Replace these paths with actual, locally accessible paths to the Client and Client.Runtime DLLs
$hive = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14"
$assemblies = @()
$assemblies += $hive+"\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$assemblies += $hive + "\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
$assemblies += "System.Core"

# Code for accessing the SharePoint client object model
$cSharp = @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
namespace SPClient
{
    public class CustomClass{
        public static string GetFieldSchema()
        {
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(`"http://your/SharePoint/url`");
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(`"List Name Here`");
            Field field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(`"Field Name Here`");
            clientContext.Load(field);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            return field.SchemaXml;
        }
    }
}
"@

# Here's the magic where you load the above code and reference the assemblies
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSharp -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies    

# Now you can invoke the custom code to get the XML string
[xml]$schema = [SPClient.CustomClass]::GetFieldSchema()

# Parse the XML as normal
$array = @()
$schema.Field.Choices.Choice | %{ $array += new-object psobject -property @{Choice=$_} }
$array | Export-CSV -notype -path "\WhereverYouWant\YourFile.csv"
```

Answer (score -1):

Retrieving the site object then referencing the .choices property does the trick.

For a client operating on a 2007 environment code is as follows.

```
$spsite=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]("<site url>")
$rootWebSite=$spsite.RootWeb
$rootWebSite.Fields[0].Choices
```